# Python + Paramiko - Checking whether two files are identical without downloading

Tags: python, sftp, checksum, paramiko

I have a script that downloads a lot of fairly large (20MB+) files. I would like to be able to check if the copy I have locally is identical to the remote version. I realize I can just use a combination of date modified and length, but is there something even more accurate I can use (that is also available via paramiko) that I can use to ensure this? Ideally some sort of checksum?

I should add that the remote system is Windows and I have SFTP access only, no shell access.

Comment: can you run remote scripts? also are you trying to check for benign changes or malicious changes?

Comment: Benign changes. Actually, due to the fact that the timing on the servers may or may not be reliable, of bigger concern are two files which *are* identical but have different timestamps. So ideally I could use a checksum to confirm that two files were the same even if one were newer than the other. I think in this case & based on the type of file (log file) I'm going to assume that the files will only get *longer*, so if the files are the same number of bytes then they're the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I came with a similar scenario. the solution I currently take is to compare the remote file's size by using item.st_size `for item in sftp.listdir_attr(remote_dir)`  with the local file's size by using `os.path.getsize(local_file)`. when the two files are around 1MB or smaller,this solution is fine. However, a weird thing might happen:  when the files are around 10MB or larger, the two size might differ slightly,e.g., one is 10000 Byte, another is 10003 Byte.

Comment: It turns out the difference in size is caused by float precision. use df.round() can eliminate this problem.